# Angular/TS: how to get the values of properties from partial extended interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

Very new to Angular/TS and maybe I have phrased this wrong but I will try to explain as best I can.

I have 2 interfaces, one extends the other like this:

```
export interface CustomerModel {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
    //other things
}

export interface OrderModel extends Pick<CustomerModel, 'firstName' | 'lastName' {
  orderNumber: number;
}
```

I have created a service with a hardcoded instance of Customer (working local on machine and for now everything is hardcoded. I will eventually work with DB but I need this to work this way first)

```
export class CustomerService {
  customers: CustomerModel[];
  constructor() {
    this.customers = [{
     firstName: 'John',
     lastName: 'Doe',
    //more here 
       },
{
     firstName: 'Jane',
     lastName: 'Smith',
    //more here 
       },
     ]
   }

   getCustomers(): Observable<CustomerModel[]> {
    const customers = of(customers);
    return customers;
 }
}
```

Now I am trying to create an Order Service using the OrderModel

```
export class OrderService {
  orders: OrderModel[];
  constructor() {
    this.orders = [{
     orderNumber: 123;
     firstName: ???, //what do I put here to pick up the name from CustomerModel
     lastName: ???,
       },
     { 
    //more here 
       },
     ]
   }

   getOrders(): Observable<OrderModel[]> {
    const orders = of(orders);
    return orders;
 }
}
```

When I hover over the value of firstName in my orderservice, it does say it is from CustomerModel so I know that the extended worked.
If I leave firstName and lastName out of the orders array, I get an error saying that OrderModel is expecting them.
Maybe this is not possible and there is possibly a better solution but I have been going round in circle trying to see if this works.
Can anyone help me get the value of the property firstName/lastName from the CustomerModel?

Comment: May be change OrderModel extends Pick<Customer to OrderModel extends Pick<CustomerModel

Comment: Sorry that was a typo and it set to that. My problem is what do I put in for firstName so that it picks up the firstName from CustomerModel?

Comment: instead of firstName and lastName , the OrderModel should have Customer Id .So , Customer Model should have an Id field . Give 0 , 1, 2 like that and give same customer Id in OrderModel instead of firstName and lastName .

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking to replicate the data from the one service, but add ids to each item? Or are you having an intellisense problem?

Comment: @AdityaYada sort of yes.. I must have a value for firstName/lastName but I want it to be the name in the customerModel. I don't know what to put in the orderService so that it picks up "John Doe" on the order form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet in this case is to have a separate file that holds all the base data for the user, and then transform that to whatever you need later.

```js
// app/some-folder/customers.ts
export const customers: CustomerModel[] = [
  {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    //more here 
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    //more here 
  },
];
```

And in the service

```js
import { customers } from '@app/some-folder/customers.ts'

export class CustomerService {

  public getCustomers(): Observable<CustomerModel[]> {
    return of(customers);
  }

}
```

```js
import { customers } from '@app/some-folder/customers.ts'

// map the existing customers, and transform it to also have an orderNumber
// use ...a, orderNumber: i to merge the whole customer add orderNumber together
const orders: OrderModel[] = customers.map((a, i) => ({
  firstName: a.firstName,
  lastName: a.lastName,
  orderNumber: i,
}))

// or you can do this, which is more in-line with how an API would respond
// generally an order would just include the customerId, or have a customer object
// const orders = customers.map((a, i) => ({ customer: a, orderNumber: i }))


export class OrderService {

  public getOrders(): Observable<OrderModel[]> {
    return of(orders);
  }

}
```

This way when you implement the API, all you have to do is swap out the bodies of your functions.

Comment: This gives me the full customer. Does this work with partial customer?? Can I just bring in the 2 properties I need and not the full model? I am getting error that is it missing a bunch of fields

Comment: @SiobhanHolubicka
Updated the code to demonstrate just taking specific properties